# How to change a \n value for a value like X

Tags: php

I have a webpage for homework. Students fill in the boxes, then click send to send the form.
My php thankyou file gets the answers and sends to my email. I download the emails and use Python to check each answer against the correct answer, line for line using readlines().

This morning I noticed, one student missed the first part, 1 to 5 'choose the right word from the table.' They should just enter a letter, A to E, in each textbox, G1 to G5. The email sent by php then contains 5 empty lines, \n, where the answers should be.

Because students often press enter in strange places, I run a Python script to get rid of empty lines in the emails after downloading.

So I would like to get php to put say X if a textbox is empty, before it sends the email.

The first part of the thankyou.php looks like this:

```
//should mail the contact form
<?php
$studentnr = $_POST['sn'];
$q1 = $_POST['G1'];
$q2 = $_POST['G2'];
$q3 = $_POST['G3'];
$q4 = $_POST['G4'];
$q5 = $_POST['G5'];
```

What I would like to do in php is something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(1, 6):  
    answer = $q + str(i)  
    if answer = '':  
        answer = 'X'
```

but that would be Python. What is the right way to do this in php?

I think this should be done after collecting all the $qs in the php script, but before making the body of the email:

```
$body = "

Studentnr = ".$studentnr."
".$q1."
".$q2."
".$q3."
".$q4."
".$q5."
";
```

Very grateful for any tips!

Edit: this is an actual thankyou.php with the loop to change '' for X, but all I get now in the email is: Studentnr = 1725010999, nothing else. How to tweak this? I just entered the student number and left all other boxes empty, so I was expecting a lot of Xs. I am not getting any errors in the error log of my php directory on the webpage host. Maybe a ; missing somewhere?

```
//should mail the contact form
<?php
$studentnr = $_POST['sn'];
$q1 = $_POST['G1'];
$q2 = $_POST['G2'];
$q3 = $_POST['G3'];
$q4 = $_POST['G4'];
$q5 = $_POST['G5'];
$q6 = $_POST['G6'];
$q7 = $_POST['G7'];
$q8 = $_POST['G8'];
$q9 = $_POST['G9'];
$q10 = $_POST['G10'];
$q11 = $_POST['G11'];
$q12 = $_POST['G12'];
$q13 = $_POST['G13'];
$q14 = $_POST['G14'];
$q15 = $_POST['G15'];
$q16 = $_POST['G16'];
$q17 = $_POST['G17'];
$q18 = $_POST['G18'];

for ($i=1; $i <= 18; $i++) {
    if (${"q$i"} == '') ${"q$i"} = 'X';        
}

$body = "

Studentnr = ".$studentnr."
".$q1."
".$q2."
".$q3."
".$q4."
".$q5."
".$q6."
".$q7."
".$q8."
".$q9."
".$q10."
".$q11."
".$q12."
".$q13."
".$q14."
".$q15."
".$q16."
".$q17."
".$q18."
";


$to1 = "myemail@foxmail.com";

$subject = $studentnr . "sWeek1";
$headers = "From: peter@mypage.com\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

mail($to1, $subject, $body, $headers);

header("Location: email_success.php");

?>
```

Any more tips please?

Edit again: Normally, I get the answers OK. I'm just trying to correct for an empty answer. If a student does not fill out 1 box, and I remove empty lines, all the answers after the empty line are in the wrong order, so the score is very bad. I will go back to Q1 = ".$q1." Q2 = ".$q2." in the body part if I can't get his to work. At least I have a line!

Here is a paragraph of my html. If you see anything wrong, please let me know. I generate this from a text file with Python.

```
<p>
<b> World Recession </b> <br>
W: Now people are talking about <INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="G1" size="15">, which started more than a year ago. Can you give us your personal understanding of the situation of the global economy? <br>
M: As you know, we are in a very special time. This is a very hard time for many countries&#39; economies, both <INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="G2" size="24">. <br>
W: What challenges is our economy facing at the moment? <br>
M: We do face a lot of challenges because there is still much uncertainty about the world&#39;s economy. 
It&#39;s very important for us to strike a <INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="G3" size="14"> between investment in <INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="G4" size="14"> and household consumption. <br>
</p>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
   for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $answer= ${'q' . $i};
        if($answer=='') $answer='X';        
    }
```

Edit:
If you just only need to update value, you can do that like this,

```
   for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if(${'q' . $i}=='') ${'q' . $i}='X';        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It occurred to me that I need to reassign the $qs at the end. Like this maybe: for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $answer= ${'q' . $i};
        if($answer=='') $answer='X'; ${'q' . $i} = $answer;      
    } Will that be OK like that??

Comment: Oh yes I just converted the python code as you requested. if you wanna replace with X just replace them directly on if statement. I ll update my answer.

Comment: Tried several times, but I am not getting any Xs in the email, still just empty lines. Any ideas please?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, can you check what this returns `echo $q1;` if you also share your HTML it will be better. You might be making a mistake over there, make sure your inputs look like this `<input type="text" name="G1"><input type="text" name="G2">` etc.

Comment: Thanks again. The html normally works fine. If I insert values, I get them in the email, no probs. I'll post a bit just to show it.

Comment: I am blind, stupid and careless! I am sorry to have troubled you! My webpage form uses thankyou18BEsW1.php, but I had another file thankyou18BE1sW1.php Of course, if I change the latter, the email cannot change!! Now I have altered the correct file, everything works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I m glad it helped if you accept the answer, I'll be happy thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change any of the `$q*` variables to `'X'` if they are empty, you can use PHPs [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to do that. For example:

```
$q1 = '';
$q2 = 'A';
$q3 = '';
$q4 = 'E';
$q5 = 'D';
for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if (${"q$i"} == '') ${"q$i"} = 'X';        
}
echo "$q1\n";
echo "$q2\n";
echo "$q3\n";
echo "$q4\n";
echo "$q5\n";
```

Output:

```
X
A
X
E
D
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sYehs)

Comment: So I don't need to reassign variables via $answer, just directly reassign ${"q$i"} = 'X'; That's great, I'll try it asap!

Comment: @Pedroski no, no need to use an intermediate variable, you can do it all in one line.

Comment: I visited your link and the code works, but in my email I am not getting any Xs. Any idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: It's possible you are getting some whitespace characters in the values, try changing `if (${"q$i"} == '')` to `if (trim(${"q$i"}) == '')`

Comment: Thanks again! I tried that, but still no Xs in the email. I also tried if (${"q$i"} == ' '), if (${"q$i"} == '\n'), if (${"q$i"} == '\c') No joy! Don't know where the problem lies, works great in your link!

Comment: I am blind, stupid and careless! I am sorry to have troubled you! My webpage form uses thankyou18BEsW1.php, but I had another file thankyou18BE1sW1.php Of course, if I change the latter, the email cannot change!! Now I have altered the correct file, everything works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pedroski no worries - I'm glad you figured it out.